# Two proof questions about eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

a. How do I prove that if $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalues of $A^2$ then at least $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

b. I want to show that an invertible linear transoformation $T$ and its inverse $T^{-1}$ have the same eigenvectors.

thank you!

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? We are not here to solve your homework !

Comment: well about a im not sure if its true or false to begin with

Comment: What is the underlying field?

Comment: I presume R, but its not clearly stated

Comment: @Surb Seems you habe been refuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be the eigenvector of $A^2$ corresponding to the eigenvalue ${\lambda}^2.$ Then we have
$$(A^2 - \lambda^2 I) v = 0 \implies (A- \lambda I) (A + \lambda I) v = 0.$$
So either $(A+\lambda I) v = 0.$ In which case $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $v.$  Otherwise $$(A+ \lambda I) v \neq 0.$$ Then $\lambda$ will be an eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $(A + \lambda I)v$.

For the second one let us take an eigenvector $v$ of $T$ corresponding to the eigen value $\lambda$. Then first show that $\lambda \neq 0$ and then try to show that $v$ is also an eigen vector of $T^{-1}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\frac {1} {\lambda}$. The converse can also be similarly proved.

Comment: The big $\;X\;$ as vector is pretty confusing, in particular when there are other big letters with other functions.. I'd rather go with $\;x, u, v, w\;$or something like that.

Comment: Well which one should I opt? Kindly suggest me one such according to your wish @DonAntonio. You are always welcome to do any kind of constructive edits if necessary.

Comment: If you invite constructive edits, then don't roll them back within seconds. I see you had a conflict with your own edit, but there are more elegant ways to solve that (which I implemented) than just crushing the other edit.

Comment: For the second half of the first proof, I would suggest it would be better to make a distinction as follows: either $(A+ \lambda I) v$ is zero (in which case $v$ is an eigenvector for $-\lambda$) or it is not (in which case $(A+ \lambda I) v$ itself is an eigenvector for $\lambda$, as in the part you wrote). This also avoids treating $\lambda=0$ as a special case, or having  to assume $\lambda^2\geq0$ (where is that assumption ever used).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion @Marc van Leeuwen. I have edited my answer.